# How to add your exceptions when deleting an entity having a relations on Laravel Admin?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

When deleting an entity in `Laravel-Admin` having a relationship, a not-so-informative error dialog box crashes from the user's point of view.

How to handle this exception in the framework of Laravel-Admin in order to give the user an informative error message?

Thank you for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: The code should never get to the database to cause this, you need validation instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `->onDelete('cascade')` on your foreign key in migration.

Example: `$table->foreign('point_sale_online_id')->references('id')->on('point_sale_online')->onDelete('cascade');`

But I guess that you want to achieve that user has to validate deleting something. The way I do this: delete button fires modal with confirm button, which is a submit to the form with `SomethingController@destroy` action. Nevertheless to achieve that you need to add this `onDelete` method. Then you can simply do

```
if(App\Something::find($id)->delete(){
//all good code
} else {
// something went wrong code
}
```